# mostrar solo el nombre de mi array de objetos

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de mostrar solo el nombre de mi array de objetos (el cual es un carrito de compras de un ecommerce para mi proyecto final del curso de JS)

```
localStorage.setItem("productos", JSON.stringify(cart)) 

function finalizarCompra () {
    const mistock = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("productos"))
    const compraTerminada = document.createElement("p")


    compraTerminada.innerText = `Usted selecciono: ${mistock.nombre}`

    modalCarrito.appendChild(compraTerminada)
}

let productos = [
{
    id: 1,
    nombre: "KIMONO VENUM",
    precio: 20000,
    imagen: "../multimedia/kimono.png",
    deporte: "grappling",
}
];
```

Comment: Que contiene `cart`? en `JSON.stringify(cart)`

Comment: el cart es un array vacio, el cual va recibiendo objetos cada vez que el usuario clickea agregar al carrito

Comment: puedes agregar a la pregunta, que contiene JSON.stringify(cart) como preguntó @JoseMgz_Ux? cart es un array de objetos con que propiedades?

Comment: hola, ahi agregue un ejemplo de las propiedades, quiero acceder al nombre de cada uno y mostrarlo en el html

Answer (score 1):

Si cart es un Array con objects dentro podrias usar un codigo como este

```
let template ='Usted selecciono: '
mistock.forEach(e => template += `${e.nombre},`);
compraTerminada.innerText = template
```

Notese que separe los elementos por coma, tu ves si eso te sirve o usas un

Answer (score 0):

Entonces puedes usar `map` para sacar el nombre de cada elemento y `join` para unirlos con coma. Así:

```
compraTerminada.innerText = `Usted selecciono: ${mistock.map(e => e.nombre).join(", ") }`
```